# Is there any existing database (preferred embedded ones) supporting large diminutional multi-dimentional search?

Tags: c++, database, kdtree, r-tree

I would like to build a C++ application on top of an database that can support multi-dimensional search (e.g. KDTree or RTree). SQLite with R-tree enabled only supports up to 5 dimensions, which is much smaller than I need. Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by multidimensional search? Searching multiple fields for a single value?

Comment: The multidimentional search means that you can give multiple ranges of different attributes within in single query.

Comment: What type of *queries* do you want? Single-attribute queries? Window queries? Range queries? kNN queries? NN-Joins? Reverse-k-NN queries?

Comment: And how many dimensions do you have? kD and R-trees just don't *work* on high dimensional data sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

Well, do the queries actually make *sense* this way? Euclidean distance is a reasonable distance for 2D and 3D geometric data. But even for "space-time" it does actually *not* make sense. Because 1 second is something entirely different than 1 meter.

First decide which type of distance is reasonable, then think about which index is appropriate. Depending on your queries, you will want very different indexes.

There is no "one size fits all" here. An index that performs well for one task and one data set will likely be worse than a linear scan - in particular at high dimensionality - on another.

Dynamic data and static data are again two things that are heavily different. Maintaining a well-balanced tree dynamically is *a lot* harder than bulk-loading an R-Tree with STR and just querying it with window queries. That's just a couple of lines, a good coder should be able to do in a few days.

You might want to read up on the problems of high-dimensional data, e.g. [this rather balanced article on the "curse of dimensionality"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-13818-8_34) (there are plenty of articles saying "you can't index high-dimensional data" as an excuse for failing to do so, this one at least gives you some examples on when you can and when you cannot).